# Mac OS X 10.6.5 and link-local addresses (169.254.x.x)

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard

Starting with the latest update of Mac OS X (10.6.5) all Apple applications (Safari, Mail, iChat, etc.) don't connect to the internet anymore, if the assigned IP address is from the 169.254.0.0./16 range. This is not a routing problem, I can still ping any server I want, even connecting via command line tools works.

I know this problem could easily be fixed by changing the IP address to a more common RFC1918 address (e.g. 192.168.0.0./16), but this is what the ISP assigns via DHCP and I am not sure I can convince them (Xplornet) to change that.

So I am wondering if there's a (hidden?) setting that would convince Apple applications, that they are in fact still online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, link-local address are not supposed to be used by clients getting a legitimate DHCP lease from the ISP at the very least. Your ISP basically doing something wrong.

I don't know, but maybe apple is trying to close some holes with this kind of configuration.

The easiest thing i can come up with is to add a router in between and use the DMZ functionality to forward all ports..

Comment: I know the ISP is doing it wrong, really wrong. I've thought of a router, too. Unfortunately the Apple computer I'm talking about is on the other side of the big pond and I am not sure if my in-laws will be able to configure that thing correctly without me assisting via screen sharing (which would not work while doing it...). That's why i'd love to have a pure software solution.

Comment: well most routers nowadays will have automatic dhcp on lan side, and dhcp client on wan side. the only thing you need to do would be to instruct your in-laws to shutdown the wifi or secure it... and you can consider TP-link routers as they are fairly stable, and they have emulator online.. (http://www.tp-link.com/simulator/TL-WR1043ND/index.htm)

Comment: I am having the same exact problem with xplornet and my mac.  I can use firefox, but am unable to use several other applications on the computer.  Did the addition of a router help them out?

Comment: Adding a router worked well.